# Can I use a third party framework and static libraries inside my project to create my static library so have just .a file and headers at the end?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I generally don't create static libraries so can you please help me on this;
I have a third party framework and 2 static libraries inside my project so that I will build my own static library by using them. So is it supported to put static libraries and third party frameworks into my project so that I can create my own library? I see that some of the sources say this is not supported while some say it is ok. Please let me know.

Thanks,

E.

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

technically you would export the third party framework and insert it into your library. When it comes to the static libraries, its possible from that point since your just calling one library from another.